# Does adding extension methods to ViewModel Maintain ViewModel Rules?

Tags: c#, wpf, database, mvvm, viewmodel

There are certain methods in my ViewModel that access a database connection. I know this is not correct since the ViewModel shouldn't be responsible for connecting to a database.

So as a solution, I moved some of my methods to another class as extention methods. I.e.

```
Public static void (this MainViewModel viewModel){
viewModel.Textbox = "hello";
viewModel.Tables = GetDatabaseConnectionAndReturnTables();
//...//
}
```

Is this really a way to get database connection functionality out of the viewmodel? This is the only solution I could come up with.

Thanks,

Luke

Comment: Why shouldn't it?  That should depend on your overall system design, not some perceived notion of what is and is not proper mvvm.

Answer (score 4):

> Is this really a way to get database connection functionality out of
>   the viewmodel?

Short answer: no.

Not that long answer: extension methods are meant to add methods to types when source code isn't available, you can't derive a class or you want to add them to a struct (struct aren't inheritable...).

Actually you're adding methods to your view models as if they were added as direct class members. Either if you implement them as view model instance members or using extension methods, you're implementing methods in the view model.

If you want to effectively abstract data from view models you should check some design patterns like:

- [Repository](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html).
- [Unit of Work](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html).
- [Domain model](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/domainModel.html).
- [Service layer](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/serviceLayer.html).
- [Inversion of control](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/InversionOfControl.html).
- [DTO](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html).

It would be hard to provide you more guidance about how to achieve a true separation of concerns in a Q&A format (I would need to write a book here), but I would start learning more about these design patterns.

Also, I would take a look at what's *domain-driven design*.

Answer (score 1):

Going this route could get pretty wacky. If there was a choice between extension methods and nesting the functions within the view-model, then the latter would be preferred.

*However...* both are pretty bad practice. You should read up on the [DAO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object) and [Repository](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx) design patterns. Using the `DAO` pattern, you hide the details of the database, only exposing the knowledge of a `persistence` layer. Then with the `Repository` pattern you expose methods that allow you to manipulate a particular data-set without any care for how that data is retrieved and/or stored.

Using [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) you would then inject the repository into a model that does a specific task with that data. Again, you would then pass that model into your view-model which simply displays the information that is available from the model.

Comment: DAO? This very outdated for me ;P

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer I partially agree. In larger systems perhaps, but as a stepping stone, it provides a good introduction into the separation of concerns and abstraction without having to juggle too many layers.

Answer (score 0):

One of the big reasons why you keep your data access out of the view models in MVVM is to help with testing. One of the huge advantages of using MVVM is in making more of your code testable, without taking a dependency on the View. By making your view model call an extension method, you have no way of abstracting out the data store calls. This means that when you do your unit testing, you must always have data in the database, ready to be queried against. It also means your data base will fill up with a bunch of crap data that is inserted when your unit tests are ran. You want to hit your data-base when you are writing integration tests, but not really when you are just testing the functionality of your view models.

Abstracting the data access out in to a service or repository, that is hidden behind an interface allows you to test your code, without having to deal with having a connection to the database. You would create [fakes](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/582812/Unit-testing-with-Fakes-with-Visual-studio-Premium) or [mocks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object).

This way, your code would do this:

```
private IMyRepository repository;
public MainWindowViewModel(IMyRepository repo)
{
    this.repository = repo;
}

public Task SaveObject(MyObject obj)
{
    return this.repository.Save(obj);
}
```

When you unit test, you just provide a mock, or fake, to your view model constructor and let it hit the `save` method on those instead.

Your use of an extension method still means you are tightly coupled to your data-layer. It might be abstracted in to a different file, but your view-model is still tightly coupled due to the fact that you can't swap out the data-access without re-writing the original extension method.

The other benefit of this, is that other view models may use the same methods if they need to ask for data. This saves having to copy & pasting the code into extension methods for each view model that might need it or creating an instance of a view model just to get access to its extension methods to fetch your data. View models are typically limited to one view, but the data they are provided with can be used on *n* views.